# INSERT statement for Class Table Inheritance model

Tags: sql, postgresql, inheritance, foreign-keys, insert-into

I have two tables defined as follows:

```
create table MY_COMPONENT (
ID uuid,
VERSION integer not null,
CREATE_TS timestamp,
CREATED_BY varchar(50),
UPDATE_TS timestamp,
UPDATED_BY varchar(50),
DELETE_TS timestamp,
DELETED_BY varchar(50),
DTYPE varchar(31),
--
PRODUCT_NUMBER varchar(255),
DESCRIPTION varchar(255),
MANUFACTURER varchar(100),
--
primary key (ID)
)
```

and

```
create table BASE (
ID uuid,
primary key (ID)
)
```

BASE is a subclass of MY_COMPONENT.

I have the following constraint:

```
create unique index IDX_DEIPRODUCTCONFIG2_MY_COMPONENT_UK_PRODUCT_NUMBER 
on DEIPRODUCTCONFIG2_MY_COMPONENT (PRODUCT_NUMBER) where DELETE_TS is null 

alter table DEIPRODUCTCONFIG2_BASE add constraint FK_DEIPRODUCTCONFIG2_BASE_ID 
foreign key (ID) references DEIPRODUCTCONFIG2_MY_COMPONENT(ID)
```

What I am trying to do is something like

```
INSERT INTO BASE(ID, VERSION, PRODUCT_NUMBER, DESCRIPTION, MANUFACTURER);
```

As I've discovered this exact syntax doesn't work because `BASE` doesn't have a `PRODUCT_NUMBER`, `DESCRIPTION`, or `MANUFACTURER` as those are store in the `MY_COMPONENT` table. I've also tried to insert a row in `MY_COMPONENT` with `NEWID()` and using that same `ID` to try and insert into `BASE`. I also tried the inverse of this, inserting the `BASE` first then using its `ID` to insert into `MY_COMPONENT`. Both of these throw errors regarding unique constraint violations.

As I am sure is clear, I am very new to database programming. These tables and constraints are not my creation; I am using the CUBA Platform for development and these table creation scripts are automatically generated for me. I do understand the syntax for the CREATE statement but the purpose and use of the FOREIGN_KEY isn't really clear to me. Perhaps that is my missing link. But any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably miss a point, but I can't reproduce your problem, the insert in  `MY_COMPONENT` then `BASE` seem fin to me...

Anyway, if you want to do it with a stored procedure, here it is :

```
CREATE FUNCTION addbase(
    version INTEGER,
    product_number VARCHAR(255)
  --
) RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
    uid uuid := uuid_generate_v4();
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO my_component(id,version,product_number) 
    VALUES(uid, version,product_number);
    INSERT INTO base(id) 
    VALUES(uid);
END ;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql /
```

---

Full answer

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/998ca/2)

**PostgreSQL 9.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp"
/
create table MY_COMPONENT (
ID uuid,
VERSION integer not null,
CREATE_TS timestamp,
CREATED_BY varchar(50),
UPDATE_TS timestamp,
UPDATED_BY varchar(50),
DELETE_TS timestamp,
DELETED_BY varchar(50),
DTYPE varchar(31),
--
PRODUCT_NUMBER varchar(255),
DESCRIPTION varchar(255),
MANUFACTURER varchar(100),
--
primary key (ID)
)
/
create table BASE (
ID uuid,
primary key (ID)
)
/

create unique index IDX_DEIPRODUCTCONFIG2_MY_COMPONENT_UK_PRODUCT_NUMBER 
on MY_COMPONENT (PRODUCT_NUMBER) where DELETE_TS is null 
/
alter table BASE add constraint FK_DEIPRODUCTCONFIG2_BASE_ID 
foreign key (ID) references MY_COMPONENT(ID)
/


CREATE FUNCTION addbase(
    version INTEGER,
    product_number VARCHAR(255)
  --
) RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
    uid uuid := uuid_generate_v4();
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO my_component(id,version,product_number) 
    VALUES(uid, version,product_number);
    INSERT INTO base(id) 
    VALUES(uid);
END ;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql /
```

**Query 1**:

```
insert into MY_COMPONENT(ID,VERSION,PRODUCT_NUMBER) 
  values(uuid_generate_v4(), 1,'1-dynamic')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/998ca/2/0)**:
**Query 2**:

```
insert into BASE(ID) select ID from MY_COMPONENT where PRODUCT_NUMBER ='1-dynamic'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/998ca/2/1)**:
**Query 3**:

```
insert into MY_COMPONENT(ID,VERSION,PRODUCT_NUMBER) 
  values('774033f8-52a6-4b1f-8602-03ce3c5a7432', 2,'2-static')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/998ca/2/2)**:
**Query 4**:

```
insert into BASE(ID) 
  values('774033f8-52a6-4b1f-8602-03ce3c5a7432')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/998ca/2/3)**:
**Query 5**:

```
select addbase( 44,'3-stored-procedure')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/998ca/2/4)**:

```
| addbase |
|---------|
|         |
```

**Query 6**:

```
select * from MY_COMPONENT
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/998ca/2/5)**:

```
|                                   id | version | create_ts | created_by | update_ts | updated_by | delete_ts | deleted_by |  dtype |     product_number | description | manufacturer |
|--------------------------------------|---------|-----------|------------|-----------|------------|-----------|------------|--------|--------------------|-------------|--------------|
| e48124ff-a26c-4d10-93a7-48da77b613e6 |       1 |    (null) |     (null) |    (null) |     (null) |    (null) |     (null) | (null) |          1-dynamic |      (null) |       (null) |
| 774033f8-52a6-4b1f-8602-03ce3c5a7432 |       2 |    (null) |     (null) |    (null) |     (null) |    (null) |     (null) | (null) |           2-static |      (null) |       (null) |
| b6ecb3ce-e3c2-4f68-8a19-9cfceeba1263 |      44 |    (null) |     (null) |    (null) |     (null) |    (null) |     (null) | (null) | 3-stored-procedure |      (null) |       (null) |
```

**Query 7**:

```
select * from BASE
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/998ca/2/6)**:

```
|                                   id |
|--------------------------------------|
| e48124ff-a26c-4d10-93a7-48da77b613e6 |
| 774033f8-52a6-4b1f-8602-03ce3c5a7432 |
| b6ecb3ce-e3c2-4f68-8a19-9cfceeba1263 |
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. I was trying to run my queries through the function to run update scripts built in to the Cuba Studio. I moved my test scripts to the INIT_DATA script that Cuba runs when creating a database and the data was successfully inserted. I'm not sure if that is a bug on their side. Thank you kind soul.

Comment: @no-one you're welcome, I added a stored proc if you want to do the double insert in one go ;)